# How to deserialize xml in c++ using boost

Tags: c++, xml, serialization, boost

There are many answers for serialization.

For serialization/reconstruction in C++, here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost\archive\xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost\archive\xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost\archive\binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost\archive\binary_iarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;


void serialization();
void reconstruction();
int main()
{
    serialization();
    reconstruction();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void serialization(){
    int id = 100;
    string name = "Mike";
    Student student(id ,name);
    string filename("student.xml");
    std::ofstream ostreamXml(filename.c_str());
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oabin(ostreamXml);
    oabin<<BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(student);
    ostreamXml.close();
}

void reconstruction(){
    std::ifstream inputStream("student.xml");
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive iArchive(inputStream);
    Student student2(2,"dfds");
    iArchive>> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(student2);
    inputStream.close();
    cout<<student2.takeExam(2,3);
}
```

In this case, I can reconstruct the object since I know the type of the serialized object, which is "Student". But what if I don't know the type of the object that is going to be deserialzed?

Thanks!

Comment: you need a factory object/method here, i don't remember whether boost::serialization provides one or you have to write one yourself

Comment: First of all, "XML from C#" is confusing, because it doesn't matter at all how exactly XML is created if the format is strictly defined. Regarding deserialization, every application should control it on its own. If your stream consists of various objects in any order, then you certainly should store them together with kind of object type ids. E.g. make an enum with object types and serialize one its value before serializing each object. When deserializing, you will always know what kind of object goes next, because at first you deserialize its type as your enum value.